# Any way to resolve the "another window manager is already running" error with dwm in OS X?

Tags: macos, xorg, dwm

I know it should be possible to run `dwm` in OSX Mountain Lion, since it is possible to run X11 (or xQuartz). However, whenever I try to run `dwm` I just get

```
dwm: another window manager is already running
```

in the terminal and it fails to start. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`killall quartz-wm`

If it kills the whole X session (because wm was last line in the init script), modify your .Xinitrc script and replace `quartz-wm` with dwm

Answer (score 1):

Just paste the following into `~/.xinitrc.d/00-dwm.sh`:

```
USERWM=/usr/local/bin/dwm
```

And make the file executable (`chmod +x`).